# Синхронизация времени события

Tags: php

На сайте есть события, они имеют время происшествия, надо выводить их время относительно времени пользовател, как сообщения в вк...допустим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала вам требуется узнать у пользователя его часовой пояс. Для этого есть 3 способа:

1. Определить по IP. Самый плохой способ, поскольку не всегда по IP
   можно определить даже страну, не говоря уже о городе. Вдобавок,
   нужно будет держать информацию о часовом поясе для каждого города
   мира.
2. Попросить пользователя указать свой часовой пояс. Самый
   частоиспользуемый способ. Как правило, часовой пояс запрашивают при
   регистрации пользователя на сайте. А зная часовой пояс пользователя,
   можно без проблем узнать смещение относительно базового времени
   сервера.
3. Узнать через JavaScript. Самый оригинальный способ. В данном способе
   надо, используя объект Date, отправить на сервер информацию о текущем часе пользователя. Далее на сервере надо посчитать разницу между текущим часом базового времени на сервере и тем часом, что пришёл от пользователя. Далее
   сохранить в cookie или сессию это смещение. Вот и всё.

Пример:

```
  $user_timezone = 'Полученный от пользователя часовой пояс';
  date_default_timezone_set($user_timezone); // Часовой пояс по умолчанию.
  echo date(); // Любое время будет выведено относительно настроенного часового пояса
```

Comment: понял один момент, они ведь у меня указывают город :D можно исходя из этого сделать))

Comment: но однако  спасибо)

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев город весьма сложный вариант. Для вашего случая проще просить пользователя при регистрации указывать часовой пояс.